# leafletjs mapbox tiles not always loading

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

sometimes, normally with a drop in connection but not always, not all tiles load with mapbox via leafletjs

Is there a way to handle this? I am trying to sort this out with

```
tile_layer.on("load",callbackToNativeForMapStartedSuccess());
tile_layer.on("tileload",callbackToNativeForMapFinishedLoadSuccess());
tile_layer.on("tileerror",function(error, tile) {
        callbackToNativeForMapFinishedLoadError(error.message)});
```

where I use callbackToNativeForMapFinishedLoadError to reload. But this doesn't always get called when some tiles are not loaded.

The callback to native is simply because I am executing this from within a WKWebView on iOS but that should make no difference

Answer (score 0):

I guess `error.message` is incorrect. Look at the following snippet from https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.7.3/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L581

```
layer.fire('tileerror', {
            tile: this,
            url: this.src
        });
```

The first argument is the tile itself and the 2nd is the url of the tile.